# Separate joint distribution from conditional joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

What is the relationship between $P(A|B,C) \text{ and }  P(A|B)$, such that $P(B,C)$ is joint distribution? Using product rule, I got so far as to $$P(A|B,C) = \frac{P(A, B, C)}{P(B,C)}$$, but I do not know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that: $\def\P{\operatorname{\rm P}}~~~\P(A,B,C) =\P(B,C)\P(A\mid B,C)$

It is also so that: $\P(A,B,C)=\P(B)\P(A\mid B)\P(C\mid A,B)$

Clearly, therefore :$$\dfrac{\P(B,C)\P(A\mid B,C)}{\P(A\mid B)}=\P(B)\P(C\mid A,B)$$

Comment: awesome. Thank you!